# Does Hindley-Milner refer to the unification algorithm for type reconstruction, a type system, or a form of polymorphism?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, types-and-programming-languages

What does Hindely-Milner refer to?

1. In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce, I only find that Section 22.4 Unification mentions "Hindley" and "Milner", when introducing the unification algorithm.

   Does Hindley-Milner refer to the unification algorithm for type reconstruction/inference?
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system refers to Hindley-Milner as a type system.

   Where does *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce define Hindley-Milner as a typing system?

   Is a Hindley-Milner type system the same one which I heard:

   > Hindley-Milner is a special and restricted form of parametric polymorphism, in that it only allows `∀` to appear at the beginning of a type. That is, you cannot have types like `∀α.(∀β.β→β)→α`.

   ?
3. What is the relation between Hindley-Milner as a type reconstruction/inference algorithm and as a type system?

   Does the unification algorithm by Hindley and Milner apply only to the Hindley-Milner type system?

   Does type reconstruction/inference (what I saw in Ch22 Type Reconstruction in Pierce's book) only apply to polymorphic systems, not to monomorphic systems?

   Section 22.2 defines type reconstruction/inference as:

   > "Is some substitution instance of t well typed?” That is, can we ﬁnd a type substitition σ such that σΓ |- σt : T for some T?
   >
   > Looking for valid instantiations of type variables leads to the idea of type reconstruction (sometimes called type inference),

   The footnote of Ch22 on p317 says

   > The system studied in this chapter is the simply typed lambda-calculus (Figure 9-1) with booleans (8-1), numbers (8-2), and an inﬁnite collection of base types (11-1). The corresponding OCaml implementations are recon and fullrecon.

   Does that imply that type reconstruction/inference only apply to polymorphic systems or also to monomorphic systems?

Thanks.

Also appreciate if you could consider [What is "Hindley-Milner (i.e., uniﬁcation-based) polymorphism"?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115206/what-is-hindley-milner-i-e-uni%ef%ac%81cation-based-polymorphism)